# single file git deployment into server

Tags: git, deployment, capistrano

I'm using Capistrano for deployment of rails application; how can one file be updated on the server without making a new release?

For example :

Suppose I made changes to only my `UserController.rb.` and committed it the to git server,
how should I get this update onto the server without making a new deployment.

Comment: Surely the whole point of having a deployment system is that you actually use it, rather than trying to circumvent it?

Comment: @Andrew : Thanks for your comment ,But still its not clear to me,In brief should We do the whole deployment process for only one file update.

Answer (score 11):

Capistrano has a deploy task for updating single files where a full deploy isn't necessary.

```
cap -e deploy:upload
```

In your case it would probably be like this:

```
cap deploy:upload FILES='app/controllers/UserController.rb'
```

You might also have to restart your app

```
cap deploy:restart
```

Comment: same as here: http://www.frick-web.com/en/blogposts/capistrano-single-file-deployment - works perfect!

Answer (score 2):

You should make a new release through Capistrano.

The purpose of a deployment tool is to give you repeatable results and to help you to keep track of what you've deployed.  Circumventing this process for a small fix means that you lose both of these advantages.  If you think that running your whole deploy process for a simple change is overkill, then you should probably work on streamlining the process (or on making sure that you never have to perform a simple fix -- good luck with that!).

Pragmatically, I'm sure many people would just edit the file manually on the server.  Not recommended, for the reasons given above.  If you think the trade-off is worth it, that's your call :).

As a disclaimer:  I'm not a ruby developer and I've never actually used Capistrano, my advice is generic rather than specific to those technologies.  Maybe there is a special way to push small changes through the system -- if so, I'd have expected an answer pointing it out...

Comment: Well I understand the the deployment is useful for tracking the releases.But still I just want to know the do I can make changes on only file without using any ftp client .Please help me if you have any idea ...
By the way thank you so much for you reply .

Comment: If you are trying to push s/th to a test or staging server you may not care as much about roll-backs or tracking of releases. That is you are not touching mission critical servers, and you might just want to fix a typo or something else real quick w/o having to wait through a huge deploy. Depending on your app may take quite a while.  

But in general I agree it should be used very wisely and seldom if  not at all on production boxes.

Answer (score 0):

The task `cap deploy:upload` doesn't exist anymore in Capistrano 3.
You can add this gem https://github.com/Reiknistofa/capistrano-upload to get it back.